# Calculate total and average from a file

Tags: java, file, csv, io, try-catch

I am trying to calculate total and average numbers from scores.csv but some reason it doesn't calculate.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TotalAndAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File("Scores.csv"));
            double total = 0, count = 0;
            while (fin.hasNextInt()) {
                total += fin.nextInt();
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Total score is " + total);
            System.out.println("Average score is " + (total/count));
            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Scores.csv does not exists!");
        }
    }

}
```

When I run it shows,
 `Total score is 0.0 Average score is NaN` 
do you know why? I checked my file and it has data in it.

Comment: *I checked my file and it has data in it.* - what does this data look like?

Comment: Scores.csv

2 4
5 3
6 5
4 4
4 5
3 2
2 3
6 5
4 4
5 6
5 3
3 4
6 4
2 4
4 6
5 5
6 5
3 4

Comment: Because you are not reading anything , if total and current both are `0` then it's simply `0/0` which is undefined and NAN(not a number)

Comment: The "Scores.csv"  string is inside the file? Note that `fin.hasNextInt()` returns false if it finds something that cannot be understood as an integer (like "Scores.csv"). This would botch your `while` loop from the very beginning.

Comment: Adding to what @rslemos said, the Scanner does not seem to find `integers`

Comment: `Scanner` is not an appropriate tool to read a CSV file, at least, not without a lot of effort. You should use a CSV library.

Comment: no, Scores.csv is the file name and I have data in it. All data in Scores.csv is integer.

Comment: Then it's not a CSV file, since CSV stands for *comma*-separated values.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you ladies and gentlemen..

Comment: @Sami given that your issue may be related to the data (the code seems fine, though I personally never used `java.util.Scanner`), I can only recommend you to use a debugger to find out what you are really getting from the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 2):

As others in the comments have explained, the Scanner class's `hasNextInt` method works by breaking up the input stream into tokens, and returns false as soon as it hits a token that is not an integer. It's possible that there's non-number data in there for some reason that it's picking up on and returning false for.

A more proper way of handling this data would be to use `hasNext()` to control the termination of the while loop, allowing you to loop through each token of the file, skipping non-integer tokens and then terminate after all tokens have been consumed, not just when the first non-integer token is found:

```
while(fin.hasNext()) {
  if(fin.hasNextInt()) {
    int integer = fin.nextInt();
    total += integer;
    count++;
  }else{
    fin.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: As per @sami comment *All data in Scores.csv is integer*

Comment: Yeah, All data in Scores.csv is integer. Thank you though!

Comment: Ah dang @ScaryWombat I didn't see that message there. I've modified the answer to be more general in case someone else comes across with that problem. It's a weird one though. I can't trick it into giving me the same results with any weird spacing characters.